# Random_state for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, anaconda, precision-recall

I am looking to create a for loop in Python that selects a random_state number that returns the highest recall coefficient in a classification report. Below is the code I tried.

```
import pandas as pd

dataw = pd.read_csv('bankrup.csv')

dataw =dataw.dropna()

X=dataw.values[:,1:]
y=dataw.values[:,0]


print("Logisrtic regression")


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

for i in range(1000):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=i)

#Random forest
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=5000,  class_weight="balanced")
                            

logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
print('test set score :',logreg.score(X_test, y_test))

#Confusiton matrix and clasification report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
print ('\n confussion matrix for the test set :\n',confusion_matrix(y_test,
                                                                    y_pred))
print ('\n classification report for the test set :\n',
       classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

I am looking for a good recall coefficient for Class 1.0 and changing the random_state number gives me a different result everytime. How do I make a for loop that changes the random_state everytime and "remembers" the number that gives the highest recall coefficient.

I hope my question is clear, if not I will answer any question.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

#### Your `for` loop covers too little code

Indent the entire rest of your code, so it is run separately for every random_state value.

Then, for each, calculate the `recall_coefficient`.

If that `recall_coefficient` is better than the `best_recall_coefficient`, update the `best_recall_coefficient` and the `best_random_state`